# Based on a condition in a column in data frame, remove data in other columns of the same row

Tags: r

I wonder how I remove all the data from all other columns in a row when trt=C. I'm interested in a solution that would work for a lot of columns!

```
A <- sample(1:100,9)
B <- sample(1:100,9)
trt <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3) 

df <- data.frame(trt, A, B)
df

    trt A  B
1   A  32 43
2   B  29 79
3   C  94 95
4   A 100 24
5   B  63 38
6   C  80 92
7   A  22 98
8   B  61 56
9   C  69 81


to look like this:
       trt A  B
    1   A 90  50
    2   B 84 100
    3   C NA  NA
    4   A 42  17
    5   B 61  43
    6   C NA  NA
    7   A 78  84
    8   B 27  36
    9   C NA  NA
```

Something like...

```
if(df$trt=="C") {
  df[,i] <- NA
}
```

Comment: Yes! It was easy:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with function `is.na<-`.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], `is.na<-`, df$trt == "C")
df
#  trt  A  B
#1   A 28 90
#2   B 80 70
#3   C NA NA
#4   A  9 78
#5   B  5 14
#6   C NA NA
#7   A 16 62
#8   B  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `[` to select rows and columns to alter, i.e.

```
df[df$trt == 'C', -1] <- NA
```

which gives,

> ```
>   trt  A  B
> 1   A 87 56
> 2   B 53 18
> 3   C NA NA
> 4   A  8  1
> 5   B 79 38
> 6   C NA NA
> 7   A 48 36
> 8   B 55 22
> 9   C NA NA
> ```

You can also use it to choose specific columns,

```
df[df$trt == 'C', -c(1, 3)] <- NA
```

which gives,

> ```
>   trt  A  B
> 1   A 96 27
> 2   B 21 13
> 3   C NA 34
> 4   A 43 98
> 5   B 70 93
> 6   C NA 64
> 7   A  2 60
> 8   B 40 94
> 9   C NA 11
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if (df$trt[i] == "C") {
        df[i, ] <- NA
        df$trt[i] <- "C"
      }
    }
```

Hacky, but works!

Comment: Why are you (not) changing `df$trt[i]` in the `if` statement?

Comment: I am only checking if `trt` is equal to C in the `if` condition. `df[df$trt == 'C', -1] <- NA` is the ideal way to do this though, soln, by @Sotos